# Error installing Mesh-to-SDF using pip in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip, google-colaboratory

I am trying to install Mesh-to-SDF but I get an error that I believe is related to installing scikit-learn (sklearn).

```
!pip install mesh-to-sdf
```

and the error is:

```
Collecting mesh-to-sdf
  Using cached mesh_to_sdf-0.0.14-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Collecting pyrender
  Using cached pyrender-0.1.45-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
Collecting scikit-image
  Using cached scikit_image-0.22.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (14.7 MB)
Collecting sklearn
  Using cached sklearn-0.0.post12.tar.gz (2.6 kB)
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you rightly guessed, the error originates here `Collecting sklearn Using cached sklearn-0.0.post12.tar.gz (2.6 kB) error: subprocess-exited-with-error` as contained in your Stack Trace. A similar issue was reported [here](https://github.com/marian42/mesh_to_sdf/issues/38). You may want to install these separately. Here is how to fix this error as referenced there:

- use 'pip install scikit-learn' rather than 'pip install sklearn'
- replace 'sklearn' by 'scikit-learn' in your pip requirements files
  (requirements.txt, setup.py, setup.cfg, Pipfile, etc ...)
- if the 'sklearn' package is used by one of your dependencies,
  it would be great if you take some time to track which package uses
  'sklearn' instead of 'scikit-learn' and report it to their issue
  tracker.
- as a last resort, set the environment variable
  SKLEARN_ALLOW_DEPRECATED_SKLEARN_PACKAGE_INSTALL=True to avoid this
  error.

Comment: Thank you, it works for me by setting SKLEARN_ALLOW_DEPRECATED_SKLEARN_PACKAGE_INSTALL=True.

Comment: Glad to help. If you like my answer, you can give an upvote. Happy coding!